# How to append javascript block in a string into html?

Tags: jquery, html

I have an ajax call which returns me following response:

```
<div class="content">
    <script language="JavaScript">  
        function validate(){
            alert('validate is working');
        }
    </script>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:validate();">my button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now, i want to convert the response into html and append it to the page, which made the ajax call.

```
$.get('test.php', function(data) {
    $('#someTarget').append($(data).find('.content').html());
});
```

I have tried above code, but it seems this only append container div. Is there a way to append javascript code block into my existing page?

Comment: What you have should work given the correct selector, you missed the `.` in `.find('.content')`. How are you confirming that the script isn't being executed?

Comment: hey @KevinB, i've just misspelled .content here - i fixed it. I assume script is not executed as i can't see validate function in DOM - and there is no alert when i click  'my button'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code are two problems:

```
$('#someTarget').append($(data).find('content').html());
```

1. `$(data)` does parse *and* execute your script, before you inserted it into DOM
2. assuming you meant `$(data).find('.content').html()` the html() returns the innerHTML of content, you only need `$(data)`.

Try this:

```
<div class="content">
    <style type="text/javascript">  
        function validate(){
            alert('validate is working');
        }
    </style>
    <div class="container">
        <a href="#" onclick="javascript:validate();">my button</a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now there is a trick: I'm using `<style>` to wrap scripts, that should be executed after interpreting and inserting into DOM.

```
$.get('test.php', function(data) {

    // parse HTML to DOM
    var $data = $(data);

    // take the scripts out
    var $inlineScripts = $('style[type="text/javascript"]', $data).remove();

    // Now append the DOM
    $('#someTarget').append($data);

    // And globalEval the scripts
    $inlineScripts.each(function () {
        $.globalEval(this.innerText);
    });
});
```

Okay for your simple validate function that gets called by a click handler, you currently don't need my trick for inline scripts, however you will need it, when you have active scripts, that should be executed after the HTML is parsed *and* inserted.

Update: If you don't want the '.content' to be inserted, don't use html() - because it returns a string, so you do parse the html twice. Use instead `.append( $(".container", $(data)) )` or `.append( $(data).find(".container") )`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'll try your suggestions - globalEval might be the thing i'm looking for. I'll let you know.

Comment: beware that `$(data)` parses and evaluates inline scripts. that is why i'm wrapping it into style and then do globalEval.