# Auto executing javascript code loaded dynamically

Tags: javascript

Let's say i have main page:

```
<html>
  // Blah blah blah
  <button />
  // Blah blah blah
<script type="text/javascript">
  // Nothing here
</script>
</html>
```

That button on the main page open a modal with the following structure:

```
<div>
  <!-- HTML Stuff -->
</div>
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function() {
    // hide stuff, show stuff
  });
  function whatever() {
    // do some stuff
  }
</script>
```

This modal is loaded into my DOM.
The question is:
**Why** the `whatever` function can't be called in the context of the modal?
For example, if i had a `select` tag inside the modal and added an `eventListener` to it so that when fired, it would call the `whatever` function, like this:

```
$('#select').on('change', function() {
  whatever();
});
```

Or even:

```
<select onchange="whatever()" />
```

If i move the function to the main page, outside the modal it works like a charm.
Does it have something to do with the code being executed and losing all references when it is loaded dinamically?

Comment: You need to show us more...Give us an example how does it not work.

Comment: Please show how are you trying to call that function.

Comment: Why don't you call whatever() from the "load success"-hook in your loadModal-routine?

Comment: I have edited the question to give more insight.

Comment: Are you sure `whatever` in global scope?

Answer (score 2):

Did you try something like this (semi-pseudo-code ;-)

**Modal:**

```
function initModal() {
    $('#select').on('change', function() {
        whatever();
    });
}
```

**Main Page:**

```
$.get('modal.html').success(function() {
    initModal();
});
```

Comment: That's a great solution to the problem, but what i really want is to understand why the problem happened.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, the dynamically loaded script is executed before the html is inserted into the DOM.

Have a look on my answer to [How to append javascript block in a string into html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381368/how-to-append-javascript-block-in-a-string-into-html/13382062#13382062)

Comment: Hmm, that's good to know. So you are saying that everything would be executed and no function reference will exist if i load it like that?

Comment: Yes, sadly I noticed this since jQuery 1.4+ (afair) that scripts are removed and no more living in javaScript global space. So if you want to do something simple you may get away with `$(document).on("change", "#select", function () { });` or a custom init that gets called in a $.get callback, but for a more general approach I made it with the style script trick/hack